# once user press 2 times y and the next time n, when enter n how to add item1 and item2 and display total price

Tags: java

[image]

once the user presses 2 times `y` and the next time `n` when they enter `n` how to display the total price of `item1` and `item2`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ITPL_Coursework {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String itemStr ;
        String quantityStr;
       final double tax=0.03;
       double total = 0;
       int price;
      char choice;

       // System.out.print("\nEnter number of the hardware component you want: "); 
        System.out.println("\tHari's Hardware Company ");
        System.out.println("\t-----------------------");
        System.out.println("\nAvailable hardware components and its price are listed below: \n1:HYPERX FURY RAM \n2:Graphics Card");

                       do{
                itemStr=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of the hardware component you want: ");
                int item=Integer.parseInt(itemStr);
                quantityStr=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the quanity of the hardware component you want:");
                int quantity=Integer.parseInt(quantityStr);

                if(item==1){
                    price=1500;
                    total=(tax*(price*quantity));
                    System.out.println("You choose to buy HYPERX FURY RAM for: " +total);
                }

               if(item==2){
                   price=1000;

                    total=(tax*(price*quantity));

                   System.out.println("You choose to buy Graphics Card for: " +total);              
               }


                System.out.print("Do you want to continue y/n?:");
                  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
                     choice=console.next().charAt(0);
                }

                   while(choice=='y');


                   System.out.println(""+total);


    }
}
```

Comment: guys the code is working fine and my lecturer say no need to use gui. When i choose titem 1 and item 2.. and then press n, i want to display the additiion of item1 and item2

Comment: now when i choose item1 and item 2, its only displaying the price of item2

Comment: Please show what your program does and explain what you want it to do differently instead. Show a specific example to illustrate the general description.

Comment: Side note: I suggest you learn about Java indenting standards. Your indentations are all over the place which distracts from reading the code to figure out what it does.

Comment: image of output------https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPvVS.jpg

Comment: You should copy/paste the output as text instead of posting an image.

Answer (score 1):

```
total=(tax*(price*quantity));
```

This only assigns `total` to be the current cost. If you want to sum all costs, then you need to use `+=`:

```
total += (tax*(price*quantity));
```

Comment: so in the end i just display System.out.println(+total); ??

Comment: bro i tried it yet its not working still showing same output see the photo i uploaded on top

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPvVS.jpg still showing price of item2

Comment: GUYS I SOLVE IT THANK YOU SO MUCHHH LOYE YALL